# Query Document to get snapshots from specific collections in Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore as the database for my app. The data structure is as below

expenses (collection)

```
     |____[userId] (doc)

                 |___[year-month] collection

                                |___[expenseId] doc

                                               |______expense fields(amount, date)
```

How can I get all expenses from a [userId] doc for specific [year-month] collections.

Is there a way to query a doc like we have .where for collection

Answer (score 0):

You have nested collections in your database, right? you can simply chain `collection` and `doc` until you get the specific target, since it's not clear what is code variables and what is plain text names, I will assume that all documents and collections names are text, just to so you get the idea:

```
// This is the reference of a the "year-month" expenses of the user.
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('expenses').doc("userId").collection("year-month");
```

this will get you a `QuerySnapshot` containing all documents inside the collection with that "year-month" :

```
QuerySnapshot = await query.get()
```

You can also get a specific document in that collection like this:

```
DocumentReference doc = await query.doc("expenseId").get();
```

Comment: I think my question isnt very clear. I want the doc refers of all the collections that specify a certain criteria like year-month=="2022-12" || '2023-01".

Comment: alternatively is there a way merge data in multiple querysnapshots into one.